# Java Blowfish decrypt not giving original string back

Tags: java, java-6, blowfish, jce

I'm implementing a simple password store using Blowfish.  All was fine until I tried out a few different password/key combinations and came across numerous instances where the decrypted values were still garbage.

Below is a standalone class that demonstrates the issue.  I get the following output:

```
'Aaaaaaa7' encrypted: 'r?—èLèdÓ,·Ã¸ÍÒ'*
'Aaaaaaa7' decrypted: 'ñü=€¼(T'*
```

Any idea what I need to do to guarantee it always decrypts correctly.

(Using jce.jar in JDK 1.6.0_26)

Thanks,

David

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class BlowfishTwoWayHashImpl {

    static {
        test();
    }

    public static void test() {
        String key = "wibble";

        String passwordToEnrypt = "Aaaaaaa7";

        String enc = BlowfishTwoWayHashImpl.encryptBlowfish(passwordToEnrypt, key);
        System.out.println("'" + passwordToEnrypt + "' encrypted: '" + enc + "'");

        String dec = BlowfishTwoWayHashImpl.decryptBlowfish(enc, key);
        System.out.println("'" + passwordToEnrypt + "' decrypted: '" + dec + "'");
    }


    private static final String CIPHER_NAME = "Blowfish";

    public static String encryptBlowfish(String toEncrypt, String key) {
        return processString(toEncrypt, key, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
    }

    public static String decryptBlowfish(String toDecrypt, String key) {
        return processString(toDecrypt, key, Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
    }

    private static String processString(String toEncrypt, String key, int encryptDecryptMode) {

        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), CIPHER_NAME);

        Cipher cipher;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_NAME);
            cipher.init(encryptDecryptMode, secretKeySpec);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt.getBytes()));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
return new String(cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt.getBytes()));
```

You're using the platform default encoding all over the place in your code. **Don't do this. It will lose data.**

When you're converting genuine text to bytes (e.g. on encryption) use a specific charset - UTF-8 is a good choice. Use the same charset to decode from "encoded text" to `String`.

When you're converting arbitrary binary data to text, use base64 encoding, e.g. via [this public domain Base64 encoding library](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/).

Basically, when you create a new string with the `String(byte[])` or `String(byte[], String)` constructors, you're saying, "This is genuine text data - please just decode it as a string." When the data is actually the result of encryption, it's *not* text data... it's an arbitrary bunch of bytes.

Comment: OK got it, I used the apache Base64 implementation instead but does the job.